# Is there a way map/set utm parameters in gtm?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I currently have a bunch of traffic going to my website with a query string like so:  www.mywebsite.com/?source=facebook

I've installed GTM on my website and also from GTM fire a Google Analytics Page View etc.  What i'm wondering is through GTM, is there a way to grab the source (facebook) from the url and set utm_source=facebook when firing the pageview tag.

Or is my only option to change all the links going to my site to be:
www.mywebsite.com/?utm_source=facebook instead?

Thank you everyone for your expert advice.  Really Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the parameters via an url type variable, and then use the "set fields" option in your GA tag to populate the "campaignSource" and "campaignMedium" fields. If the parameters are not present the url query variables default to "undefined", and undefined fields are not sent, so you do not need to check if values are present.